# Conditional multiple pattern replacement with gsub in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replace multiple patterns with gsub and grep in R.

What I have is a pattern of single and double digits, ie

```
 [1] 30 20 15 15 10 10 5  5  3  3  15 15 7  3  3  5  5  3  3  30 30 20 20 15 
Levels: 3 5 7 10 15 20 30
```

I would like to add a "Y" to each of them to have the following output:

```
 [1] 30Y 20Y 15Y 15Y 10Y 10Y 5Y  5Y  3Y  3Y  15Y 15Y 7Y  3Y  3Y  5Y  5Y  3Y  3Y  30Y
Levels: 3Y 5Y 7Y 10Y 15Y 20Y 30Y
```

I am struggling to change it for both single and double digit numbers.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
tbl %>% 
  mutate(col1 = gsub("([0-9])([0-9])","\\1\\2Y",col1)) %>%
  mutate(col1 = gsub(!grep("[0-9][A-Z]",col1),"\\1Y",col1))
```

My current output is

```
 [1] 30Y 20Y 15Y 15Y 10Y 10Y 5  5  3  3 15Y 15Y 7  3  3  5  5  3  3  30Y
Levels: 3 5 7 10Y 15Y 20Y 30Y
```

What would be the best way to solve this?

Looking forward to your thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: Could it be enough for your need: `col1 = paste0(col1, 'Y')` ?

Comment: Offtopic but maybe first change from `factor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `paste` here:

```
tbl$col1 <- paste0(tbl$col1, "Y")
```

Note that the above would convert `col1` to character, which may or may not be acceptable to you.  Also, I might even recommend *not* doing this transformation of `col1`.  Rather, consider just keeping your original numeric data as is, and then use `paste` if you want to *view* that data a certain way.

We could also use `sub` here:

```
tbl$col1 <- sub("$", "Y", tbl$col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you insist on using `gsub` you can do the following:

```
 gsub("(\\d+)", "\\1Y", col1)
```